# Python check if numbers in TXT file exists

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm a bit clueless about why my python script doesn't recognize the number that is definitely in the text file.

This is the text file:

```
001420999;
000502999;
000120999;
000126999;
001220499;
001180000;
001104799;
001123111;
```

and this is the code i'm using:

```py
with open('/var/www/html/capcodes.txt', 'r') as f:
    capcodes = capcode.split()
    for cap in capcodes:
        if cap.strip() in f.read():
            print("true")
        else:
            print("false")
```

Yes, `capcodes` is filled and he indeed gets cap.strip() without problems.

It is getting stranger, the only time it says true is with number: "001180000" the other ones don't work.

Comment: The file pointer is at the end of the file after the first `f.read()` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.read` reads the entire file. After calling it once, you're at the end of the file. Run read() once before the start of the loop and store the result in a variable, so:

```
with open('/var/www/html/capcodes.txt', 'r') as f:
    capcodes = capcode.split()
    stored_lines = f.read()
    for cap in capcodes:
        if cap.strip() in stored_lines:
            print("true")
        else:
            print("false")
```

Note that if you're looking for a full line match, you might want to do some more cleanup first, and make the file into a list:

```
with open('/var/www/html/capcodes.txt', 'r') as f:
    capcodes = capcode.split()
    stored_lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    for cap in capcodes:
        if cap.strip() in stored_lines:
            print("true")
        else:
            print("false")
```

...since otherwise, a value of '123' for cap will match if a line '12345' is in the file.